# Open gridview inside another gridview

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a gridview which contains columns `vacancy id` and  `vacancy title` and a few image buttons.

When the user clicks on button <kbd>show criteria</kbd>, another gridview should open inside existing gridview.

This inner gridview should show criteria for that vacancy.

Again, when user clicks on the same button, it should hide the child gridview.

I tried this by adding child gridview in item template part of the template field of the parent gridview, but it shows the inner gridview in another column.

However, I want to open child grid below the row whose button is clicked.

How is this accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi check this example : http://tugberkugurlu.com/archive/parent-child-view-in-a-single-table-with-gridview-control-on-asp-net-web-forms

i think for your issue you need to play with the width of the itemtemplate column. that may resolve your issue easily.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax modal popup inside GridView and it will open on button click.